# c++ atoi crashes at 1 million and above

Tags: c++, atoi

I have searched for a couple hours now and I can't seem to find anything relevant to this problem. If you have found this problem elsewhere please point me to where you found it.

I am using the `atoi(const char *)` function in c++ and all is working fine....until I tried using numbers at 1,000,000 and above.

This is where my program is crashing:

```
int toRead = atoi(argv[2]);
```

This code works fine with 10, 100, 1000, 10000, etc... until 1 million. Then I get a Windows error that Main.exe has stopped working, and it asks me if I want to debug.

I have hard coded the same code to check

```
int toRead = atoi('1000000');
```

This also crashes. I have tried atol thinking that perhaps there was not room in the integer data type. This also does not work. I also ran the INT_MAX on my system and got the standard 2,147,483,647, so an int can definitely hold 1,000,000

I then proceeded to implement the atoi method myself with this code:

```
int atoi( const char *c ) 
{
  int value = 0;
  int sign = 1;
  if( *c == '+' || *c == '-' )
  {
     if( *c == '-' ) sign = -1;
     c++;
  }
  while ( isdigit( *c ) )
  {
     value *= 10;
     value += (int) (*c-'0');
     c++;
  }
  return value * sign;
}
```

This code works just like the atoi method, in that it works fine until I hit it with 1000000.

Can someone please help me figure out why this is happening?

I am running on a nice desktop with intel i7 quad core, 16GB ram, so I do not think it is a machine issue.

Any help will be greatly appriciated.

Thanks!

Here is my whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3)
        cout << "\nUsage: " << argv[0] << " <filename> <# of elements to process>" << endl;

    else
    {
        int toRead = atoi(argv[2]);
        int arr[toRead];

        ifstream file(argv[1]);

        if (!file.is_open())
            cout << "\nCould not open file\n";
        else
            cout << "\nFile opened: Ready to process " << toRead << " numbers\n\n";

        string nums;
        int numi;
        for (int i = 0; i < toRead; i++)
        {
            getline(file, nums);
            stringstream ss(nums);
            ss >> numi;
            arr[i] = numi;
        }

        // Find minimum number
        int min = arr[0];
        time_t startTime = time(NULL);
        for (int i = 1; i < toRead; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] < min)
                min = arr[i];
        }
        time_t timePassed = time(NULL) - startTime;

        cout << "Minimum value: " << min << endl
                << "Elapsed time: " << timePassed << endl;

        file.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*** As pointed out my amyCU the error is in the array allocation of 1000000. Thank you for you help. I feel like an idiot.

### EDIT

This solved this issue:

```
int* arr = new int[toRead];
```

Comment: dude, int toRead = atoi("1000000"), not single '

Comment: I would expect this to crash because you have the wrong quotes on it `int toRead = atoi('1000000')` should be `std::atoi("1000000");`

Comment: Can you show us what you typed in at the command line that caused the crash (the *whole line*).

Comment: Using double quotes or single quotes still compiles and runs fine. Using both quotes works at numbers smaller than 1000000

Comment: I guess that the crash might happen outside of `atoi` e.g. because the result is used as some allocated size or whatever. Please show much more of your code. Compile it with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). **Use a debugger** (`gdb`) to find the exact call stack at time of crash (`bt` command in `gdb`)

Comment: My command line arguments are: main.exe instance.txt 1000000

Comment: Post this in your question, not in the comment area.

Comment: @BradStell, Please show me an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where that [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32c2d59cf9ce1647).

Comment: Can you give us a complete (simplified) working example including only the statements that cause the crash?

Comment: @BradStell  If it askes you to debug then use debug .Whats the matter then ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, Ding ding ding

Comment: Are you too lazy to include the headers while you are at it?

Comment: Please post the output of `printf("%d\n", INT_MAX);` . You may need `#include <limits.h>`.

Comment: @chris: what your Ding ding is supposed to mean (or what allusion is it)? I am not a native English speaker, so I cannot guess.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, It's a [sound effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J24PETNpak8) for a correct answer (the result being used as a size for an array on the stack).

Comment: `int arr[toRead];`  - hmm I wonder if there could be any problem here

Comment: I tried to add headers and the add code thing bugged out

Answer (score 4):

```
int toRead = atoi('1000000')
```

Use double quotes `" "`

```
int toRead = atoi("1000000");
```

See what parameter `atoi` expects -

```
int atoi (const char * str);  // a const string (Null Terminated)
```

### EDIT

The crash you see maybe be because of this -

```
int arr[toRead];  // toRead= 1 million
```

An array with automatic storage and number of elements `1 million` .Probably use dynamic allocation.

Comment: Do you think that fixes his real problem `int toRead = atoi(argv[2]);` ?

Comment: I assume he passes the values he has mentioned in his question `This code works fine with 10, 100, 1000, 10000, etc... until 1 million. Then I get a Windows error`

Comment: @Blacktempel  Using `argv` I really don't get any crashes . Give corret output .

Comment: That's pretty clear that it works the normal way, even so he seems to have some problem. Only possible thing - though just a guess - I could imagine, is to pass a index higher than `argc`.

Comment: ameyCU you are correct. It is the array allocation. I feel like an idiot

Comment: @BradStell You might feel like an idiot but I'm impressed that you were prepared to code your own (correct) version of atoi in an effort to solve your problem

Comment: @BradStell That's really appreciable and a very good practice . Cheers !! :)

Answer (score 1):

The following code compiles and works fine on my Windows 7 machine, using compiler Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate:

```
int xatoi(const char *c)
{
    int value = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    if (*c == '+' || *c == '-')
    {
        if (*c == '-') sign = -1;
        c++;
    }
    while (isdigit(*c))
    {
        value *= 10;
        value += (int)(*c - '0');
        c++;
    }
    return value * sign;

}

void so()
{
    char *p = "100000000";
    int i = atoi(p);
    cout << i << endl;
    i = xatoi(p);
    cout << i << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    so();

    int toRead = atoi(argv[1]);
    cout << toRead << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note: You need to run it from the command prompt and pass valid number as 2nd argument (`argv[1]`). I've tested it upto `100000000`.

Please compare it with your own implementation.

Comment: I have been running it from the command line. And the program works as intended with numbers under 1 million. at the 1 million mark then the program crashes.

Comment: @Donotalo Assuming he uses a valid index (as argv[1] is probably something else), your way is no different than his.

Comment: @Blacktempel: He has just posted the full code. It wasn't there when I answered.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow), since you are converting a number

```
int toRead = atoi(argv[2]);
```

then allocating on the call stack a dynamic [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLA) of that size (which BTW is not standard C++11; raw arrays should have compile time constants as their size, and VLA is non standard)

```
int arr[toRead];
```

A typical call size is restricted to a few megabytes (and sometimes much less). As a rule of thumb you should ensure that every [call frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#CALL-FRAME) on the call stack has at most a few kilobytes (on current desktops).

The solution might be to use some standard [container](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/), e.g.

```
std::vector<int> arr(toRead);
```

sicne the actual data of containers is often heap allocated.

If for some (IMHO bad) reason you are forbidden to use containers you'll need to allocate the array in the heap

```
int* arr = new int[toRead];
```

but don't forget to release the memory -to avoid [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)- later (after the last, even indirect, use of `arr`), at appropriate place, with

```
delete [] arr;
```

Compiling your program with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) then running it under the debugger (`gdb`) would have been enough to find the bug. And using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) might be helpful too.. After your code has been debugged, for benchmarking purposes, ask the compiler to optimize, e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -O -g` (since [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is able to emit debug info while optimizing, you can have *both* `-O` & `-g`). You might even replace `-O` (same as `-O1`) with `-O2` or `-O3` to ask the compiler to optimize more.

Comment: Thanks! This is for an algorithms class, so I have to use a standard array. I will try with dynamic allocation and see if that helps

Comment: 'for an algorithms class', 'so I have to use a standard array'. I'm sure you are right, but there is no logical connection between those two statements. I would have thought that using standard containers like vector would help you better concentrate on the algorithm, instead of getting caught up (like you have) in all the messy implementation details.

Comment: This is true. But we have to search through the array and find mins and maxs and do sorts. We have to time this so the least amount of overhead possible is ideal. I imagine vector has more overhead than a standard array?

Comment: @BradShell: the overhead of using `std::vector`-s is negligible, probably to the point of being non-measurable. And when benchmarking, you need to compile with optimizations turned on (`g++ -Wall -O`)

Comment: Thank you for telling me that. I have never heard of the -Wall -O flags. I will research them and use them.

Answer (score 0):

```
int toRead = atoi(argv[2]);
```

should not crash. But, you can try using `std::stoi` (C++ way of converting strings)

```
#include <string>

int toRead = std::stoi(std::string(argv[2]));
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps use the boost library to convert to integer, instead:

```
int iValue;
try {
    iValue = boost::lexical_cast<int>(strValue);
} catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast e) {
  // do some error message, or such
}
```

`http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html`

Comment: Really? boost for this?

Comment: Don't you think boost is a little overhead for replacing a simple `atoi` ?